# innerHTML of an element without id or name attributes

Tags: dom, innerhtml

Why is the following code NOT working without id or name attribute specified for the anchor element?

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#">First link</a>
<p>innerHTML of the first anchor: 

<script>document.write(document.anchors[0].innerHTML);</script>

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I add an id (or name) attribute, like that:

```
<a id="first" href="#">First link</a>
```

It starts to work.

Why is id or name attribute so important? I don't refer to it in my javascript code. I don't use "getElementById" or anything, but it still wants an id to be specified.

P.S. I tested only in IE7 (not the best browser, but I don't have access to anything better at the moment, and it can't stop me from learning :)

UPDATE:

Thanks to Raynos who gave me an idea of HTMLCollection in his answer, I've gotten a deeper understanding of what's going on here, by searching the web.

When we use `document.anchors` collection, we're actually referring to a collection of `a` elements with the `name` attribute that makes an `a` element behave as an **anchor**, and not (only) as a link.

We don't have to specify the `name` attribute if we want to refer to `a` elements as **links**. In this case we just need to use a different instance of HTMLCollection object which is `document.links`.

So the original code will work without name attribute if we modify it to:

```
document.write(document.links[0].innerHTML);
```

What a nice feeling of enlightenment! :)

Comment: It's working for me. Please elaborate on what specifically isn't working.

Comment: @WuHoUnited specify which browser, It doesn't work on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WHATWG says:](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-document-anchors)

> The anchors attribute must return an HTMLCollection rooted at the Document node, whose filter matches only a elements with name attributes.

the `document.anchors` collection needs `<a>` elements with a `name` attribute.

IE is known to have bugs where it treats id's and name's as the "same" thing. So that would probably explain why it works for `<a>` elements with an `id` attribute.

As an aside, `document.write` and `.innerHTML` are evil.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: I'm just testing basic concepts. I'll get to getElementByTagName later :)